# Enabling HTTPS for pentaho bi-server - Tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat

We are setting up Pentaho which is a BI tool. This uses Tomcat as the webserver. We tried following the below link but were not successful.

```
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc1x/01.+Enabling+SSL+in+Tomcat
```

Any help as how to set this up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case this issue is still open... running tomcat with https on port 443 requires runing the application as root. for pentaho 7.0+ this is not possible any longer so you have to stick to workarounds (ports < 1024 are restriced ports, non root users can't use them without permission) like authbind.